# Google Cloud Storage Upload object using Java API in Google Kubernetes Engine fails on 90 MB file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, file-upload, google-cloud-storage, microservices, google-kubernetes-engine

I am using Java API to upload the object to Google Cloud Storage. When I try the same code through my local system, it works fine and I am able to upload objects of 66MB and 90MB without any issues.

But when I try the same thing after the application has been deployed as a Microservice in GKE pod, it stops responding for 90MB file on writer code & just creates a 0 byte file. Though it works fine for 66MB object/file. POD is accessing file from PersistentVolume

Here is the code I am using for writing objects to the Cloud storage.

```
try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(localPathFileName))) { //path is from persistentvolume

        log.info("read all lines in stream"); //this line prints and after this nothing, no exception
        try (WriteChannel writer = storage.writer(blobInfo)) {
          lines.forEachOrdered(
              line -> {
                try {
                  writer.write(
                      ByteBuffer.wrap(line.concat("\n").getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                  log.error(
                      "Error while writing lines - " + bucketName + "/" + bucketPath + fileName);
                  e.printStackTrace();
                }
              });
        } catch (Exception ex) {
          log.error(
              "Error while uploading through writer 2 - "
                  + bucketName
                  + "/"
                  + bucketPath
                  + fileName);
          ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I am not able to understand what could be the issue here. Because the same code works fine on my local system but not on pods. I have checked the memory and CPU both are well below the upper limit.

When I try to create 90 MB file, it creates a 0-byte file.
There are no exceptions or Errors being thrown, even though I am trying to catch it at every iteration and after that.

Will someone has any idea on this like what could be the issue?

Comment: The error message or exception will give you a clue. If there is no error message or exception, add better error handling.

Comment: There are no exceptions or Errors being thrown, even though I am trying to catch it at every iteration and after that.

Comment: The post does not have enough details to be able to get a good answer. Try setting up a debugger for your service using this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/debugger/docs/setup/java#gke) then update your question with your findings.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue, it was related to jvm heap size. Basically there were 20K objects getting created with file size 90MB and there wasn't enough memory.

I increased the memory size in POD and it worked.

But I am still not sure, why the POD was not throwing any outofmemory error.